# The camera does not face the 3D graphics generated by gltfLoader. I would like to render the 3D graphics while rotating the camera 360 degrees

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to point the camera towards a 3D object generated using gltfLoader, but it doesn't face the object as expected.
Can you please assist me with this? So far, I have tried directing the camera towards the origin by using `camera.lookAt()` with parameters (0, 0, 0).
I have also assigned a Three.Vector3() as the parameter and tried storing the object generated by gltfLoader in a variable `a`, then executing `a.position` as the parameter.
However, none of these methods have worked for me. Please help me. Thank you.

The current situation is that the camera is continuously facing forward and is unable to capture the full rendering of the 3D graphics.

```
``import './style.css'

import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
// import * as dat from "lil-gui";
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger"

// const gui = new dat.GUI(); 

const canvas = document.querySelector("#webgl");

let scene, camera, renderer, model, mixer,drache;
// three.js
let rot = 0;
{
    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
            0.1, 
            1000
        );
        camera.position.set(1,2,1);

        const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        const bgTexture = textureLoader.load("./bg.jpg");
        scene.background = bgTexture;
        // const baseTexture = textureLoader.load("./textures/EYES_baseColor.jpeg");

        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        drache = gltfLoader.load("./scene.gltf",(gltf) => {
            model = gltf.scene;
            // model.ratation.y = -Math.PI;
            model.scale.set(3, 3,3);
            model.position.set(1,1,1);
            scene.add(model);
            
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
            console.log(mixer);
            const clips = gltf.animations;
            console.log(clips);
            clips.forEach((clip) => {
                const action = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                action.play();
            })
        });

        // const DragonMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        //     map: baseTexture,
        //     side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        // });
        
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        // gui.add(dragon, "intensity").min(-3).max(3).step(0.001);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        
        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
        // 可変
        pointLight.position.set(1,2,3);
        // gui.add(dragon, "intensity").min(-3).max(3).step(0.001);
        scene.add(pointLight);

        const fog = new THREE.Fog("#262837" , 50 ,100);
        scene.fog = fog;
        
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: canvas,
            alpha: true,
            antialias: true,
        });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
        
        window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
        
        animate();
    }
    // init();

    function animate() {
        if(mixer) {
            mixer.update(0.055);
        }
        rot += 0.05;

        const radian = (rot * Math.PI) / 180;
        // camera.position.x = 50 * Math.sin(radian);
        camera.position.z = 30 * Math.cos(radian);
        scene.add(camera);
        if(drache) {
            // camera.lookAt(THREE.Vector3(0,0,0).position);
            camera.lookAt(0,3,0);
        }

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}

// gsap

{
    let bars;
    function makeFrag() {
        for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            bars = document.createElement('span');
            document.querySelector('.loading').appendChild(bars);
            console.log(bars);
        }
            gsap.from(".loading span", {
                y: Math.floor((Math.random()) * Math.random()) * 100  * Math.random % 3 === 0 ? "100vh" : "-100vh" ,
                delay: 1,
                stagger: {
                    from: "random",
                    amount: 10,
                },
            })
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        makeFrag();
        setTimeout(()=>{
            const loadSec = document.querySelector('.loading_section');
            loadSec.style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.documentElement.style.overflow = "scroll";
        },15000);
    });
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    let h1 = document.querySelector('.first');
    // const splitTexts = str.split('');
    // let newArray = splitTexts.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    //     return `${accu}<span>${curr}</span>`
    // },"")
    // console.log(newArray);
    // reduceでまわす
        // splitTexts.forEach((splitText) => {
        //     console.log(splitText);
            // gsap.fromTo(
            // splitText,
                
            //     {
            //         y:200,
            //         autoAlpha: 0,
            //     },
            //     {
            //         y:0,
            //         autoAlpha:1,
            //         duration: 7,
            //         stagger: {
            //             each: 0.2,
            //         },
            //         // onComplete: () =>{
            //         //     h1.textContent += splitText;
            //         // }
            //     }
            // );
            
        // })
        gsap.fromTo(
            h1,
            {
                x:-200,
                autoAlpha: 0,
            },
            {
                x:0,
                autoAlpha:1,
                duration: 7,
            }
        );
}`
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `gltfLoader.load` returns undefined so `if(drache)` is never true. You will have to set drache = true in the callback of load function

https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load